# Why’s brush bordered columnar epithelium found in intestine and not brush bordered cuboidal when I’ve been explained that they have the same function?

Tags: human-physiology

I searched for differences between their functions which would result in their positioning but none of it satisfied the answer to my above question.

Comment: Would "It is what it is, and it appears to work perfectly fine that way" be a sufficient explanation? Or does it need to be teleological, like "the gut lumen is plenty wide enough for a collumnar epithelial lining, whereas the tubules of the kidney aren't" kind of thing? Otherwise I don't understand the question. Btw, on this site, you are expected to show evidence of your search, not just state that you did one. Thanks.

Comment: I guess teleological was the word to be used I’d like to know why the columnar epithelium is the one chosen to be in the intestine. And for the research part I tried searching it in multiple ways on the Internet, how should I prove that? By attaching files of my searches? Or was that not the correct method of research. Thanks for replying

Comment: Actually a link to any of the sites you looked at (1, better 2) would have sufficed. E.g. "Wikipedia (link) says nothing about the difference between columnar and cuboidal...)" nor does Y (link). It's not any more difficult than that. We're not lunatics. We're here to help. I tried, I hope I succeeded. In evolution, teleological often doesn't really explain things.  Birds don't have wings so they could fly. Birds are able to fly because their ancestors evolved wings, among other modifications.

Comment: "...I’d like to know why the columnar epithelium is the one chosen to be in the intestine." This is a teleological statement. Nothing *chose* columnar epithelium for the gut. It developed because it works best. Maybe many more functions are required of it, so it must be a larger cell (I really don't know.) To guess why is only that: a guess. It's the function of the cell + evolution/selection that determines the outcome.